# FME Server - Can't Enter to FME GUI

Tags: fme-form, fme-flow

I have an issue with FME Server. I can't entre GUI under admin user.

I was doing some work in there, while it got freezed. (I resubmitted running job). I decided to log out and log in. After that I can't log in.

It is Production server, I am worried, I am not sure if it is running at all.

Shall I restart it? I have found this article:
https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Server_Documentation/AdminGuide/Starting_Stopping_FME_Server_Manually.htm

But I don't see anything similar to "FME Server" or "Safe Software" in the Services.

Can you help?

Comment: Please submit a ticket to the vendor Safe Software https://community.safe.com/s/support at the bottom, they are quick to respond. If you can get log files (normally by remote desktop to the server).

Comment: What version of FME Server  (now Flow) are you using?

Comment: Version is 2020.2

Comment: can you get to url:port/fmeserver/#/systemevents/history it will show Error Logs that might help diagnose the issue.

Comment: A bit later FME appeared in services and we managed to enter GUI. But now it has a queue of jobs while there is no running job :(

Answer (score 1):

When you have these kind of issues with FME Server (or FME Flow now), you should restart your machine, this solves most of the issues. You won't see FME Server in the services, it will be show as "FME" only.
Also these kind of issues which are rare could be related to the database services that have stopped.
Alternatively you could restart the FME Server Services from the FME Server menu.

[image]

I do prefer the first option though if you can afford to restart your server.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, restarting of the machine helped me that day.